# Using Classic ASP to post XML data to a web service - Server won't pick up the string

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to call a web service with the following test code. Basically what I am trying to do is to send an XML data string to the server using classic ASP, and get the response. Now I've been stuck here for days because the server doesn't pick up the data. Here's the response I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<MAG_NotifyResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <EchoToken /> 
  <PartnerId />
  <ReturnCode>600</ReturnCode> 
  <returnMessage>Empty String Received</returnMessage>
</MAG_NotifyResponse>
```

I am not familiar with XMLHTTP, so I am not sure if it's the way I used it wrong? or I should use a different method. I tried various combination of settings and none worked. E.g.,

- I send the data string without SOAP header - it complained that I didn't use correct name space
- I tried various content-types: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" - it complained that I didn't use correct media type

Any help is appreciated!

### Here's my test code:

```
<%
DIM PostData, strStatus, strRetVal, postUrl

PostData = _
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
"<env:Envelope xmlns:env=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:ava=""http://AvailReceive/AvailRq"">" &_
  "<env:Header />" &_
  "<env:Body>" &_
     "<ava:AvailRq xmlns=""http://AvailReceive/"">" &_
        "<AvailRQString>" &_
          "<MAG_AvailNotify>" &_
             "<EchoToken>b9cdaa88-b320-4d94-9be5-fc5478729c8b</EchoToken>" &_
             "<PartnerID>ONR</PartnerID>" &_
             "<HotelCode>GLAS</HotelCode>" &_
             "<Avail><AvailDet><AvailDate>2012-03-20</AvailDate><Accom>C2T</Accom>" &_
             "<AvailRooms>3</AvailRooms></AvailDet></Avail>" &_
          "</MAG_AvailNotify>" &_
        "</AvailRQString>" &_
     "</ava:AvailRq>" &_
   "</env:Body>" &_
"</env:Envelope>"

response.write("req=" & Server.HTMLEncode(PostData) & "<br/>len=" & len(PostData))

postUrl = "https://services.itsrezexchange.com/ITSTESTAvailUpdate/availrq.asmx"

Set xmlHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlHTTP.open "POST", postUrl, false
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://AvailReceive/AvailRq"
xmlHTTP.send PostData

strStatus = xmlHTTP.Status
strRetval = xmlHTTP.responseText
set xmlHTTP = nothing
response.write("<br/>") 
response.write("status=" & strStatus & "<br/>resp=" & strRetval)
%>
```

Comment: Do you have any other working app elsewhere that using this service API?  If so use a debugging proxy such as Fiddler to observe the post to the server.

Comment: I did try to connect with their web service using ASP.NET and it was successful. But I hope to get this done in classic ASP because it integrates easily with my other code which is in classic ASP.

Comment: I'd suggest that you get an HTTP Trace of the successful transaction (from ASPNET), and get a trace of the unsuccessful transaction (Classic ASP), and compare them.  you should be able to see the difference.  The Fiddler2 tool is nice for this purpose. You'd need to install it on the server, or configure the server to connect through the Fiddler proxy.